# application of limit rules in finite limits

Tags: calculus

Show that
$$\lim_{x\to 4}\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5+x}}{1-\sqrt{5-x}}\right)=-\frac{1}{3}.$$

I am getting a zero as the limit by rationalization of the numerator?

Comment: [How to write mathematical formulas on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by rationalizing both:

$\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{3-\sqrt{5+x}}{1-\sqrt{5-x}}=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{3-\sqrt{5+x}}{1-\sqrt{5-x}}\frac{3+\sqrt{5+x}}{3+\sqrt{5+x}}\frac{1+\sqrt{5-x}}{1+\sqrt{5-x}}=
\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{(4-x)(1+\sqrt{5-x})}{(-4+x)(3+\sqrt{5+x})}$

From here you should be able to get to your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

No you are not, because when you rationalize the denominator, you get $x-4$ in the denominator, so you have zeros in *both* the numerator and the denominator.

$$
\frac{3-\sqrt{5+x}}{1-\sqrt{5-x}} = \frac{3 - \sqrt{5+x}+3\sqrt{5-x}-\sqrt{25-x^2}}{x-4}
$$
The blunt-force way of doing this is to now substitute $x=y+4$ getting 
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{3-\sqrt{9+y}+3\sqrt{1-y} - \sqrt{9-8y -y^2}}{y}$$
and this simplifies (dropping the $y^2$ term in comparison to $8y$, and expanding the square roots to lowest order in $y$) to
$$
3\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{9}}+\sqrt{1-y} - \sqrt{1-\frac{8y}{9} }}{y}
=3\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-1-\frac{y}{18}+1-\frac{y}{2}  -1+\frac{4y}{9} }{y}
= 3\left( \frac{-2y}{18y} \right) = -\frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: Remember that $\frac{4-x}{-4+x}=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 4}\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5+x}}{1-\sqrt{5-x}}\right)\rightarrow \frac{0}{0}.$
Using L'Hôpital's rule, we can write this limit as:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 4}\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(5+x)^{-1/2}}{\frac{1}{2}(5-x)^{-1/2}}\right) = \displaystyle -\lim_{x\to 4}\left(\frac{(5-x)^{1/2}}{(5+x)^{1/2}}\right) = - \frac{\sqrt{5-4}}{\sqrt{5+4}}=-\frac{1}{3}$